# JUnitCore instance reusing state between tests runs

Tags: java, testing, state, instance, junit4

The scope of my project is to run preset Junit tests on a java file (namely Passenger.java) submitted in a .zip files contained in an overall zip file. I have already completed code to unzip the files extract the content one at a time to my directory and compile it along with the test file (namely PassengerTest.java). The problem I noticed is that the test results from the first submission is carried over to the other submission. At first, I thought my submission object was not resetting on each iteration of my outer loop that calls the runTests method. However, the problem still persists after setting objects to null. So, I deduced that JUnitCore instance reuses the states tests runs.

This is my code to run the tests used in VSCode:

```
public class TestRunner {

    public static boolean runTests(Submission submission){
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        TestResultListener listener = new TestResultListener();
        junit.addListener(listener);
      
        System.out.println("Running tests... for " + submission.getStudentID());
        Result result = junit.run(PassengerTest.class);
        
        ArrayList<TestResult> finalResults = listener.getTestResults();        
        submission.setResults(finalResults);

        return true;
    }   

    static class TestResultListener extends RunListener {
        private Map<String, TestResult> testResults = new HashMap<>();
        private String currentTest;

        @Override
        public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
            currentTest = description.getClassName() + "#" + description.getMethodName();
        }

        @Override
        public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
            TestResult testResult = new TestResult();
            Description description = failure.getDescription();
            testResult.setTestName(description.getDisplayName());
            testResult.setClassName(description.getClassName());
            testResult.setMethodName(description.getMethodName());            
            testResult.setStatus("FAILED");
            testResult.setScore(0);
            testResult.setErrorMessage(failure.getException().getMessage());
            testResults.put(currentTest, testResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
            if (!testResults.containsKey(currentTest)) {
                TestResult testResult = new TestResult();
                testResult.setTestName(description.getDisplayName());
                testResult.setClassName(description.getClassName());
                testResult.setMethodName(description.getMethodName());
                testResult.setStatus("PASSED");
                testResult.setScore(1);
                testResults.put(currentTest, testResult);
            }
        }

        public ArrayList<TestResult> getTestResults() {
            ArrayList<TestResult> finalResults = new ArrayList<>(testResults.values()); 
            testResults.clear();
            return finalResults;
        }
    }
}
```

To make my conclusion I reduced the test class to just test the constructor of each Passenger.java file submission. I set up the last submission in the .zip file which contains three submissions to fail and the first to pass. The results were that all passed. I did the opposite by setting the first submission to fail and the other 2 to pass but the results were that all failed.

Before I made a full conclusion, I decided to run my code in IntelliJ IDEA Debugging environment to keep track of all attribute state and discovered that a different JUnit core object was reused for each test but the results of the above were still the same.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue I'm currently facing. It will be greatly appreciated.